# Open WordPress Editor "New Post" with predefined values

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using WordPress (6.2.2) to create a software documentation website. I've adapted the post types and categories to my purposes. I made a template in order to show data as I want, and everything is working fine.

Now, I want to add some links in my template which should point out to WordPress Editor: one link to "Add New", and other to "Edit".

In the case of "existing posts", there's the WP function `edit_post_link()`, which is fine, since it includes the post ID, so all information will be loaded in the Editor correctly when it's opened.

When it comes to "Add New" link, I can't find the proper WP function that provides me this link. Anyway, I thought I can build this link from the "Edit post" link or just by copying the actual link from WordPress's Editor page.

But what really brings me here to you is that **I need to pass some values to the Editor (GET), in order to it'll load with some predefined values**: Category IDs, Template IDs and Post Parent ID. This way, the user don't have to select these values by him/herself (in fact, it would be great if these fields will be "locked" to the user ¬¬...).

I've tested adding `post_title` parameter to the "New post" link, and it shows the text in the right box:

`/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page&post_title=Hello+world`

Then I added another parameters to the link, like `post_parent` and `category/categories/cat_ID`..., with no effect on Editor's fields.

I've read and partially tested `the_editor()` and `wp_editor()` functions reference, but it seems that they add an Editor interface to my template, and that's not what I want.

I thought it could be solved by adding some filter at my *functions.php* file? In other templates I've added custom post types and custom fields, with their respective meta boxes for Editor, so I thought that would be the way to do it? It's just I don't know where to begin...

What should I do? Is there a way to do what I need?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've highlighted (bold text) my question.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't achieve what I wanted in my original question: load predefined values at Post Editor page's fields ("Parent" and "Categories") from URL's query parameters.

But I achieved something else: Even I cannot see the Parent and Category values at Post Editor's page, I can access to them by $_GET array. This means that we can manage its values from PHP directly.

In order to save the predefined values received by url (GET), I add this hook to my backend (in my case, inside my plugin, but it can be at functions.php file):

```
<?php
function myplugin_save_my_custom_type($f_id, $f_post, $f_update)
{
  # Filters my custom post type posts:
  if ($f_post->post_type != "my_custom_type")
  { return; }
  
  # Filters on creating post only:
  if ($f_update)
  { return; }

  # Assigns Parent Post ID to my Post:
  wp_update_post(
      array("ID"          => $f_id,
            "post_parent" => $_GET["post_parent"])
  );
  # Assigns Category ID:
  wp_set_post_categories($f_id, $_GET["category"]);
}
add_action('save_post_my_custom_type', 'myplugin_save_my_custom_type', 10, 3);
?>
```

Hope this helps to somebody else. I think my original question was to narrowed, and that was the reason nobody couldn't help me. Sorry for that. I'll be more accurated next time. Thank you anyway.

References and help found at:

- [Is there a save_post hook for custom post types? at WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63478/is-there-a-save-post-hook-for-custom-post-types)
- [save_post_{$post->post_type} at WordPressDeveloper](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/)
- [wp_update_post at WordPress Developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/)
- [wp_set_post_categories at WordPress Developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_categories/)